# SQL Server : get row order number in given month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server and trying to get the order of transaction in a month, for example if I have 10 transactions in a month I want to know when the selected transaction occurred, if it was the 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc. transaction in that month. I tried using `ROW_NUMBER()` like

```
SELECT
    transactionid, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY transactionexecutiontime ASC) rowOrderNumber 
FROM   
    dbo.exportebop 
WHERE 
    MONTH(transactionexecutiontime) = 1 
ORDER BY 
    transactionexecutiontime ASC
```

This works if I do not specify the `TransactionID` because I get multiple rows, the moment I use `TransactionID = idNumber` It returns a single row and row_number() is always 1

I know `ROW_NUMBER()` counts the result set but I need a way to calculate when order number in a month using the `TransactionExecutionTime` instead.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: And what happens when your table has rows from multiple years?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all months listed, you can partition the row number by month:

```
SELECT
    transactionid,
    Month = MONTH(transactionexecutiontime),
    rowOrderNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        PARTITION BY
            MONTH(transactionexecutiontime) -- Will start different "row numbers" for each month
        ORDER BY 
            transactionexecutiontime ASC)
FROM   
    dbo.exportebop 
ORDER BY
    MONTH(transactionexecutiontime),
    transactionexecutiontime ASC
```

If you want a particular transaction ID, you can't filter it on the same result set as the `ROW_NUMBER()` because it will only generate a row number for that result set, which will only contain 1 row (your filtered transaction). You will have to filter it on a another query that references the first (with a CTE or a subquery):

```
;WITH RankedTransactionsByMonth AS
(
    SELECT
        transactionid, 
        Month = MONTH(transactionexecutiontime),
        rowOrderNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY
                MONTH(transactionexecutiontime) -- Will start different "row numbers" for each month
            ORDER BY 
                transactionexecutiontime ASC)
    FROM   
        dbo.exportebop 
    -- No Order by in subqueries without TOP!!
)
SELECT
    R.*
FROM
    RankedTransactionsByMonth AS R
WHERE
    R.transactionid = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to apply `Row_Number` first then after that you can apply `filtering`. I will use `CTE` to do that -

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        TransactionID,
        ROW_NUMBER()  OVER(ORDER BY TransactionExecutionTime ASC) rowOrderNumber
    FROM dbo.EXPORTEBOP
    WHERE MONTH(TransactionExecutionTime) = 1
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE TransactionID = 1
ORDER BY rowOrderNumber ASC
```

As a sub-query-

```
DECLARE @Month INT = 1
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        TransactionID,
        ROW_NUMBER()  OVER(ORDER BY TransactionExecutionTime ASC) rowOrderNumber
    FROM dbo.EXPORTEBOP
    WHERE MONTH(TransactionExecutionTime) = @Month
) X
WHERE TransactionID = 1
ORDER BY rowOrderNumber ASC
```

Comment: You my friend are a genius, could you please explain how your query works before I accept it?

Comment: Query execution start from "FROM clause" then "WHERE clause" then "SELECT clause".....So, if we applied where condition first then row_number function in select will have only one row to give orderNumber.

Comment: What we did above is, We applied row_number function on all rows then after that we applied where clause(TransactionID=1) on that result. Hope so I am able to explain.

Comment: do you know a way I can use this as `subquery`?

Comment: Also where `MONTH(TransactionExecutionTime) = N`  N is dynamic